# Center menu (ubermenu)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I'm trying to center the ubermenu for WordPress. In plugin it says

> Center (requires Menu Bar Width) Alignment relative to the theme container.
>
> The theme's container limits the maximum width of the menu bar.
>
> If the theme's container element is 500px, the Full Width setting
>   will make the menu 500px wide.
>
> If you choose "Center", you must set a
>   Menu Bar Width below.

I have set Menu Bar Width to 100, but then it just center and make a dropdown for one link.

I dont know what to set on : Menu Bar Margin Top and Menu Bar Margin Bottom.

The url is <del>http://94.247.169.169/~welloteket/</del> - can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Add theses CSS properties to these elements to center the main menu :

```
#ubermenu-nav-main-1100-primary {
    text-align: center;
}

#ubermenu-nav-main-1100-primary > .ubermenu-item { 
    float: none; 
}
```

Comment: Hello, I just updated my answer, I changed the selector with ">"

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ejcn9h also the background for the menu dont follows at the side

Comment: i've tested it on chrome and firefox, I don't see the issue with background menu, on which browser are you testing ?